# Troubles merging branches with GitHub for Mac

Tags: github, github-for-mac

I am trying to get the hang of merging branches with the GitHub for Mac GUI. I'm not sure if it's me or the client at this point....

I have a repo with master, staging, production branches. I created a file in master called test.txt. I then added a test line to it. I committed and synced in the master. I merged from master to staging using the gui, then hit merge. I also re-clicked "branches in sync" to re-sync them. The new line shows up in GitHub under master, but not under staging. In my local repo, it shows both in sync with that latest commit.

My plan was to edit in master, merge to staging to deploy and test, rinse, lather & repeat until it's good, then merge to production (at this point all should be in sync).

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you merged master into staging and not the other way around?

Comment: Are you doing this on command line?  If so, can you show your command line history?

Comment: Yea, I was extra careful to make sure it was the right direction. Also this wasn't on the command line, so no command history

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That looks like [GitHub for Mac issue 3](https://github.com/baldwindavid/github-for-mac-issues/issues/3):

#### Merging branches does not recognize new changes to sync

> It seems that **when merging the receiving branch does not recognize that new changes can be synced with Github**
>
> Steps performed
>
> - add and checkout "`experimental`" branch
> - add/commit to `experimental` branch
> - merge `experimental` branch into `master`
> - `master` displays button "`Branch in Sync`" even though it is no longer in sync - pressing button does nothing
>
> How to fix
>
> - add a new commit directly in `master`
> - "`Sync Branch`" appears and can sync to Github

---

The [OP skinnygeek1010](https://stackoverflow.com/users/775600/skinnygeek1010) reports:

> I've found a nice workaround:
>
> To merge master with staging, merge with the GUI.
>   When it's finished, switch to staging and then go to the drop down menu: `Repository > Synchronize` (<kbd>Cmd</kbd> <kbd>S</kbd>).
>   The merge will instantly show up on GitHub (won't work if you Sync in master though)

Comment: Thanks!!! Their fix worked 1/3 times!!
Is there a way I can safely just push up the merged branches from the command line. For example commit to master, merge with GUI, then open the command line and push staging or something?

Comment: @SkinnyGeek1010 Actually, the "GitHub for Mac" help page (http://mac.github.com/help.html) mentions a push operation; "If you would like to perform a standard pull or push without syncing everything, you can do so via the Repository menu item". So no command-line necessary just yet: try the GUI first.

Comment: Thanks VonC!!! I've found a nice workaround with your help

To merge master with staging, merge with the GUI. When it's finished, switch to staging and then go to the drop down menu: Repository > Synchronize (Cmd S). The merge will instantly show up on GitHub (won't work if you Sync in master though)

Comment: @SkinnyGeek1010 Interesting feedback, thank you. I have included it in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: The desktop GUI is useless. It refuses to let me publish anything to the master. They are making a simple thing a difficult task.